# В чем различия между Git и SVN?

Tags: git, svn, контроль-версий

Вопрос, собственно выбора. Чем Git лучше или хуже SVN? Почему чаще от разработчиков я слышу именно про Git и его удобства, чем про SVN, хотя как по мне, все что слышал можно делать и в SVN.

Причём для обоих вариантов есть удобный Tortoise, что сводит общение с репозиториями практически на один уровень.

Может просто что-то плохо рекламируют, а разницы вообще нет?

Comment: Если вы работали с тем или другим, то вы знаете, чем одно лучше другого. svn - наследие прошлого, уродливое и неповоротливое. Если вы планируете работать в одной ветке, что в корне неправильно, то для вас разницы действительно нет.

Comment: @pirj Расскажите, пожалуйста, если у вас найдется минутка, почему вы пришли к такому выводу.

Comment: в svn блокировки файлов.

Comment: @eicto Только как опциональная [альтернатива стандартному copy-modify-merge workflow](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.vsn-models.copy-merge) для бинарных файлов.

Comment: >Если вы работали с тем или другим, то вы знаете, чем одно лучше другого

@pirj мне кажется, что ТС задал этот вопрос именно потому, что он не работал с тем и другим. 
И да, вы забыли аргументировать ваше бесспорно взешенное мнение

Comment: да ладно, вы сейчас человека на svn уговорите, аргументы в инете и их много... я бы ещё понял если бы выбор между git и mercurial был. а svn это кошмар. не знаю как там разработчикам, я его админил.

Comment: Еще есть такая штука как Mercurial - тоже довольно таки удобная

Comment: @pirj, я работал только с свн,только на трёх машинах и на одну изменения переносились флешкой. Т.е. по факту два разных рипозитория синхронизировались перелитием физически кода, с одной машины, на другую. К сожалению, все чеки, само собой теряются.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать
@DreamChild
К svn все прелести git уже не прикрутить. Надеюсь, вы не сильно скучаете по централизованному репозиторию. Или вы до сих пор ещё им пользуетесь?

Вспоминаю те времена, когда либо нужно было руками экспериментальный код сохранять в папки с дикими именами backup{1-30}, либо коммитить нерабочий код в репозиторий, либо не коммитить и дрожать, что что-то сломаешь. С git такой проблемы нет.

Как в svn шла разработка - это было похоже на современный CI. Но при этом своих веток у разработчиков не было.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать
@DreamChild

svn тупо медленнее. В разы.

Развернуть свой git сервер - действительно дело 15 минут (gitolite). При этом уже с распределением прав доступа пользователей к репозиториям.

Comment: У Subversion есть преимущество: в одном хранилище можно расположить все проекты. Идеология GIT требует каждый проект хранить в отдельно хранилище. Т.е. если вы пользуетесь платными услугами, как например JIRA, то за каждое ваше хранилище придётся платить отдельно. (наверное, поэтому они и закрыли услугу Subversion.)

Comment: @MaLS JIRA - багтрекер, а репозиторий VCS. Github действительно берёт деньги примерно по доллару за репозиторий в месяц. Но SVN хостинги берут деньги за занятое репозиторием место, а учитывая то, что в SVN репозитории та же история изменений займёт куда больше места, получится куда менее дёшево.

Так что никакого преимущества тут нет. Ко всему прочему, имеется немало сервисов, предоставляющих и бесплатный хостинг приватных репозиториев git - gitorious, bitbucket, assembla, последние два с ограничениями, но тем не менее.

И это для тех, кто по какой-то причине не осилит установить gitolite.

Comment: Был идентичный вопрос: hashcode.ru/questions/113235/visual-studio-системы-контроля-версий

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. GIT распределяется, а SVN - нет. Другими словами, если есть несколько разработчиков работающих с репозиторием у каждого на локальной машине будет ПОЛНАЯ копия этого репозитория. Разумеется есть и где-то и центральная машина, с которой можно клонировать репозиторий. Это напоминает SVN. Основной плюс в том, что если вдруг у вас нет доступа к интернету, сохраняется возможность работать с репозиторием. Потом только один раз сделать синхронизацию и все остальные разработчики получат поолную историю.
2. GIT сохраняет метаданные изменений, а SVN целые файлы. Это экономит место и время.
3. Система создания branches, versions и прочее в GIT и SVN отличаются значительно. В GIT проще переключатся с ветки на ветку, делать merge между ними. В общем GIT я нахожу немного проще и удобнее, но бывают конечно иногда сложности. Но где их не бывает?

Разумеется есть гораздо больше отличий, но я перечислил те, которые чаще всего встречаются при работе с репозиториями и на МОЙ взгляд наиболее важные.

Comment: - У вас часто не бывает доступа к интернету, когда вы работаете?
- Это, естественно, неправда. И Subversion, и Git хранят дельты изменений. См., например, http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-4.html и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127692/svn-performance-after-many-revisions

Comment: ну пусть не часто нет интернета, но не будете же Вы отрицать, что наличие полной копии репозитория на локальном компьютере это не отличие? Я просто привел пример, когда это может быть полезно. На счет файлов - спасибо, просветился.

Comment: @zhenyab полная копия репозитория - это и плюс и минус сразу. это удобно, если надо бранчиться от старых ревизий, часто такое бывает? коммитить в случае гит, конечно можно и без интернета, т.е. генерить ревизию... но так ли надолго пропадает интернет, что это не подождет? все равно другие девелоперы не увидят вашего коммита. а вот места жрет длинная история в больших проектах не слабо, ну и зачем мне ревизии 3-х летней давности если в день присходит несколько коммитов?  
надо идти от предполагаемого workflow. выбрать подходящий, дальше уже выбирать систему.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, то что Вы сказали - это очевидно. Для этого и был задан вопрос, чтобы ТС смог взвесить все за и против и выбрать что ему подходит лучше.

Comment: @zhenyab я комментарий писал ради:
 
>надо идти от предполагаемого workflow. выбрать подходящий, дальше уже выбирать систему.  

https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows отсюда, в частности.  
а отличия, в том числе в вашем ответе, - ни о чем.  

ЗЫ вовсе не очевидно.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov ну если atlassian для вас авторитет, то и CVS - подарок судьбы. эти ребята корчат из себя много больше чем представляют. Про jira которую они во все дыры пихают(хотя она для сегмента >middle business) я молчу. Но вот недавно  ещё с HipChat столкнулся. Я согласен с первым оратором - svn на новом проекте это как минимум глупо. (какой-то тренд в последню неделю - достать svn из могилы, в closed circles тож обсуждали)

Comment: @eicto это одна из первых ссылок в гугле по git workflows. не знал, что они вам лично чем-то насолили, привел бы третью или пятую ссылку. извините, чо.  

Вопрос у ТС из разряда какую мне выбрать БД - "oracle или sqlite или вообще dbase" и ответ "оракл - дорого и круто, sqlite для телефона только и годится и dbase - прошлый век". а для чего и как будет использоваться - пофиг, главное чтоб авторитеты были в теме. :-/

Comment: кстати, распределенная система нужна не только чтобы "когда инета нет", а чтобы можно было свою часть локально в своей-же ветке разрабатывать и не выкатывать ее пока она глючная и мешает другим разработчикам.

Comment: Для меня тот факт, что с git можно работать локально - большой плюс. К примеру, можно поработать в самолете. Или к примеру, начал делать свой маленький проектик - тут же добавил в git. Если что то не так - удалил.
Еще большой плюс локальности - для больших команд. Пришел новый разработчик - давать ему доступ на коммиты сразу - глупо (если это только не Кармак или ван Россум). А так - коммитить он может себе, может запушить это кому-то из разработчиков ( да, я знаю, в свн есть диффы. )

Comment: @kovadim, а как же разделение по веткам? Можно новичкам дать отдельную ветку... Вообще, каждому разработчику по ветке, общий сброс в тестветку и ведущий прогер все сливается в релиз.
Да, что-то локально и свн хранит, так что откаты можно производить, однако хранить гигабайты кода на локальной машине - зачем?

Comment: Новички они такие. Чуть не досмотрел - а он уже пол репозитория переработал.

> однако хранить гигабайты кода на локальной машине - зачем?

а никто не заставляет гигабайты хранить. можно удалять у себя ненужные ветки, делать git gc. Но в случае, если внешний репозитарий испортился, его можно восстановить из локальных копий. Только не говорите о бэкапах - иногда средства бекапа бывают такое выдают.

Comment: Заблуждаетесь, СВН точно так же хранит дельты, а не полные версии файлов.

Comment: 2 и 3 пункт -- неграмотный бред.

Answer (score 3):

Git сложнее для освоения.

Лично мне git предпочтительнее, позволяет мне проще сделать больше разного. Например реорганизовать порядок и содержание коммитов. Работа с ветками имхо удобнее и быстрее, через git stash удобно проверять перед коммитом что не забыл добавить вновь созданный файл. Удобнее переносить свои наработки в разные ветки - создать локально ветку, в ней вести разработку, потом просто сделать merge ветки, в svn же нужно просматривать лог на предмет нужных коммитов и переносить их ручками.

Comment: *проще сделать много разного*. Ну-ну. И как часто вы это много разное делаете? Сколько рабочего времени тратите?

Answer (score 2):

Так же распределённость git может быть полезна при восстановлении данных. Был случай когда накрылся жесткий диск на сервере, и все удалось восстановить благодаря локальным копиям. 
(P.S конечно лучше иметь зеркальные RAID, но дно другого не исключает).

Comment: Восстановить данные помогает бекап, а не распределенность. Если вы не делаете бекапы, а уповаете на распределенность гита, то что-то вы точно делаете не так. Учитывая что ваш локальный рефлог отличается от того что был на сервере, вы таки потеряете какие-то данные.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы в качестве одного из краеугольных отличий назвал бы еще lock
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html
git удобнее тем, что не надо бегать с криком "уберите замок пожалуйста". С другой стороны, встает ряд дополнительных вопросов с merge кода, который впрочем при должном навыке с помощью инструментов git нормально решается.

Comment: Локи это элемент который в гите не может быть реализован и это минус гита. Много где требуется система lock modify unlock. И если она у вас принята, то не просто так. Либо много неопытных разработчиков, либо работаете с бинарными данными.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала у нас контора работала на svn без веток, потом начали активно использовать гит с ветками, сейчас я устроился в другую контору которая работает на svn с ветками, и если честно каждый раз когда приходится сливать ветки - я с такой грустью и тоской вспоминаю гит, как там всё было просто и удобно, интуитивно понятно, и как кропотливо приходится трястись над каждым конфликтом, над каждым изменённым файлом в обеих ветках, когда гит большую часть умел разруливать сам.
А заливание каталогов в svn вообще убивает если честно.

Comment: Для полноты ответа, уточните, чем вас "убивает" заливание каталогов в svn?

Comment: Ну это опять же после сливания веток, когда в шторме смотришь список модификаций, там ещё изменённые папки попадаются. Если коммитить частями, чтобы разгрести 100500 изменений можно вместе с папками зацепить изменённые в них файлы, хотя в такой случае для svn опять же крайне нежелательно коммитить частями, т.к. это возможно только пока текущая ветка используется только мной.

Comment: Коммитить частями? Через интеграцию webstorm? Интуитивно понятно в гит? Вы хоть документацию по svn читали, не? Может доку стоит почитать?